# Looking for sample application which demonstrates drawables for different screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image, android-screen, android-screen-support

Anyone know where I can find a decent sample application (the resources folder in particular) which demonstrates the use of images (icons etc) for different screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this gonna help you: 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/MultiResolution/index.html